# Notebook `ContentsManager`, tests, and `Untitled.ipynb`

Tags: unit-testing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am subclassing `ContentsManger` to create a package to save Notebook data to an OpenStack Swift Store.

I have the basics working - as in I can connect, and starting up a notebook will create a root `container` in the SwiftStore.

What I need to do now is get the `ContentsManager` tests to not `ERROR`, but to `Fail` (and then, eventually, `pass`)

Currently I'm getting a `No such entity: [Untitled.ipynb]` error.... which I kinda half understand - as in there is no such file in my code-base.... but half don't understand - as I can find **no** reference for it using *google-foo*!

**My test environment**

I'm testing my code in a stand-alone environment.

I'm building a Docker image (based on `jupyter/base-notebook` - so Notebook 5):

`FROM jupyter/base-notebook
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    vim \
    build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    less \ 
    && apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install nose pytest pytest-cov python-coveralls
COPY . SwiftContentsManager/
WORKDIR SwiftContentsManager
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install .`

(this creates the docker image, giving me all the stuff a Notebook should have, and then installs my current code into it.)

I start the Docker:

```
docker run --rm -it **bunch-of-environment-variables** image-name /bin/bash
```

and then run the following command from within the Container:

```
py.test -v --debug swiftcontents/tests/test_swiftmanager.py
```

I've also run

```
nosetests -v --logging-level=DEBUG swiftcontents/tests/test_swiftmanager.py
```

In either case, the first test to run is `test_check_and_sign`, and it fails thus:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/tests/test_manager.py", line 605, in test_check_and_sign
    nb, name, path = self.new_notebook()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/tests/test_manager.py", line 256, in new_notebook
    full_model = cm.get(path)
  File "/home/jovyan/work/SwiftContentsManager/swiftcontents/swiftmanager.py", line 42, in get
    return func(path=path, content=content, format=format)
  File "/home/jovyan/work/SwiftContentsManager/swiftcontents/swiftmanager.py", line 148, in _get_notebook
    return self._notebook_model_from_path(path, content=content, format=format)
  File "/home/jovyan/work/SwiftContentsManager/swiftcontents/swiftmanager.py", line 178, in _notebook_model_from_path
    self.no_such_entity(path)
  File "/home/jovyan/work/SwiftContentsManager/swiftcontents/swiftmanager.py", line 136, in no_such_entity
    self.do_error("SwiftContents[swiftmanager] No such entity: [{path}]".format(path=path), 404)
  File "/home/jovyan/work/SwiftContentsManager/swiftcontents/swiftmanager.py", line 133, in do_error
    raise HTTPError(code, msg)
tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (SwiftContents[swiftmanager] No such entity: [Untitled.ipynb])`

So where does `Untitled.ipynb` come from?

(I assume I need to have it in my test SwiftStore Container - but why? surely the point of a test-suite is to assume a "start from where there's nothing" - why would there be an assumption that a test-file should pre-exist - it wouldn't, in the real-world)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it turns out that most of the Notebook code assumes, and uses, file-systems directly, and not the `ContentsManager` - so never going to fly...